# Search for specific number in column and fill cells from its adjacent cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of employee ID's for each period of the year. Each ID has Specific stats for that time period. The problem I'm running into is the list order changes every period according to the employees tasks.

Cell 1A contains the Employees ID#(ID's are Numbers only if that makes a difference). Column B has the whole list of employee ID#. I need to figure out how to write a formula or vba that checks column B for the ID# that matches 1A and populate 1C-1J with the adjacent data found in column B (columns C-J).

I hope I explained myself correctly without being to confusing. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vlookup formula looks at the first column of $B:$J (column B) and searches for $A$1 and if it finds it returns the value in the 2.(3.,4.,...,9.) column of $B:$J

A1 | B1 | =VLOOKUP($A$1,$B:$J,2,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A$1,$B:$J,3,FALSE) | =VLOOKUP($A$1,$B:$J,4,FALSE) | ... | =VLOOKUP($A$1,$B:$J,9,FALSE)

Comment: You, my friend, are amazing! Thank you so much!